# How to send dropdown selected item text to controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i need to send selected dropdown item text, not value,  to controller.
Here is the view code

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
      {
      <div class="container">
          <div class="form-group">
              @if (ViewBag.CountryList != null)
              {
                  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, ViewBag.CountryList as SelectList, "choose country", new { @class = "form-control" })
              }
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </div>
      }
```

In controller i tried to access the request context of the submitted form, but it returns the value, not the text of selected item. Please help to retrieve the text of selected dropdown item to controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `Id` and `Value` field from `Value` property of your ViewBag
Try this :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryId, new SelectList(@ViewBag.CountryList, "Value", "Value"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass you model (**replace YourModel  with you model**)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(YourModel objModel)
{
    var CountryId = objModel.CountryId
}
```

Comment: I tried so, but it will send value attribute value of the option tag not, the the text between opening and closening tag. Found the way to send text of the element to hidden input field using Jquery

```
<script>
    $("#cars").on("load", function () {
        $("#hidInp").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
    });
</script>
```

but it's too complicated. Please, advice other solutions.

Comment: @P3ar1baron
share your code for ViewBag.CountryList

Comment: here you are 

List<Country> CountryList = db.Countries.ToList();
            ViewBag.CountryList = new SelectList(CountryList, "CountryId", "CountryName");

Comment: try this 
ViewBag.CountryList = new SelectList(CountryList, "CountryName", "CountryName");

and 

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryName, new SelectList(@ViewBag.CountryList, "CountryName", "CountryName"), new { @class = "form-control" })